# Interaction in fractional polynomial regression in R using the mfp package

Tags: r, interaction, fractional-polynomial

I am modelling the relationship between waist circumference and triglycerides using fractional polynomials and the mfp package in *R*. I want to assess whether this relationship differs for ethnic groups, i.e. test if curves are parallel, by including an interaction term ethnic x waist. All this while adjusting for confounders.

This was easily done in STATA:

`fp <waist>: reg tri c.<waist>##i.ethnic age smoker drinker physact drug`

My *R* code (without interaction term):

`mfp(tri ~ fp(waist, df = 4, select = 0.05) +  age + smoker + drinker + physact + drug + ethnic, data = data, family = gaussian)`

I have not yet found out how to include the interaction term in in R with this package. According to this page https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/examples/asa/r-applied-survival-analysis-ch-5/ a solution is to first find the fp powers, then store these as transformed variables to the original dataframe, create product terms between the transformed variables and the ethnicity variable, and finally include these in a regression model. However, I am not sure if this will be correct - in STATA the interaction term is included in the model selection for optimal powers, while the latter method in R includes the term *after* the powers have been chosen.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Hello, have you managed to find a solution to this issue? I am also currently trying to fit a model in R using both fractional polynomials and interactions terms for a specific variable. I have spoken to a lecturer at my university and their intuition was to use the method you have outlined above, to calculate the MFP terms and then calculate the interactions with each MFP term separately. Would be good to get a textbook reference for this though. I am pretty sure there is not automatic way to do this in R, so you must do it manually, as you have described above.

Comment: Hi! I ended up e-mailing S. Lücke, who is the maintainer of the mfp package. At the moment, testing for interaction has not been implemented in mfp/R. However, I got the impression that they had extended mfp to test for interactions using survival endpoints only, but not when applied to continuous outcomes (as was my case). He recommended the mfpi procedure in STATA.